# How to get the language from the cache?

Tags: 8, caching

I am working on the drupal 8 website, which is presented in 3 different languages. The issue for me is that when the user switches the language on the panel, some parts of the website (block in the sidebar) don't get updated. Does the Drupal 8 Cache store the language? If yes, how can I retrieve it?

I tried to apply the 'Contexts' when I render my block build(), but it doesn't affect anything.

```
return array(
    '#type' => 'markup',
    '#markup' => $render,
    '#cache' => array(
      'contexts' => ['languages:language_interface'],
      'max-age' => 0
    ),
```

Comment: Yes, by default the render cache stores and retrieves for each interface language a different version.

Comment: `languages:language_interface` is one of the default contexts that gets passed to every render array. Unless you've changed that via sites/default/services.yml, including it in your own render array won't do anything the system isn't already doing

Comment: Why max-age = 0? This disables caching of the block and causes the block to be placeholdered in the cached page and the rendering is delayed. This might be causing the issue when there is something wrong somewhere else. $render seems odd to me. Normally you shouldn't render early and put the html in #markup.

Comment: $render is html

Comment: OK, sorry I meant you shouldn't render early and then put this rendered html in #markup (if this is what you are doing, I don't know where this html is coming from).